# What is injection in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

```
public class SeatAllocationService implements Serializable {     
  @Inject   
  EntityManager entityManager; 
  //... 
}
```

I was reading Ticket-monster.2.1.6.final. This annotation made me confused. Looking up Oracle and google didn't help: According to oracle doc, @inject Identifies injectable constructors, methods, and fields. However, what is injectable constructors?

Comment: Maybe you can add section from the docs which is not clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/cdi-1_1-fr-eval-spec/):

> The @Inject annotation defined by the Dependency Injection for Java specification identifies an injected field which is initialized
>   by the container when the bean is instantiated, or an initializer method which is called by the container after the bean is
>   instantiated, with injected parameters.

The [@Inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) annotation is part of Java Dependency Injection. CDI (Content and Dependency Injection) has been updated voor JavaEE 7 but was allready a part of JavaEE 6. Read documentation about CDI here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhb.html

For this specific example. The EntityManager should be annotated with [@PersistenceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) not with @Inject. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598318/what-is-the-difference-between-inject-and-persistencecontext) SO question.